# No llegan los webhooks de pagos recurrentes de mercado pago

Tags: mercadopago

No me están llegando las notificaciones de eventos de suscripciones siendo que el testeo de Mercado Pago me devuelve 200.
¿Cules pueden ser los motivos?

Dejo detalles de lo que he realizado:
Para poder testear tengo usuarios de prueba (vendedor y comprador) y he probado con dos herramientas para generar url públicas para el testeo: ngrok y webhook.site en ambos casos cuando hago el test desde MP me devuelve un resultado 200. Pero cuando genero una suscripción nueva no me llegan las notificaciones y obviamente no se ejecuta mi controlador de webhooks.

Leí en algún lugar que hay que generar la suscripción con la app y credenciales para que los webhook funcionen alguien me puede confirmar esto? Para saber si he entendido, no debo direccionar a mi usuario a la plataforma de MP para que genere sus suscripción?

Por otro lado el JSON que recibo en caso de creación de una suscripción es el siguiente?

```
{ 
   {
    "type": "subscription_preapproval", 
    "action": "created", 
    "data": { 
          "id": "8aa698c98b7605bb018b830254ef0798" 
    } 
}
```

Donde data.id es el id de la suscripción creada?

Comment: Hola bienvenida, ¿Cuál es en realidad el problema?, al parecer solo deseas saber como se reciben los datos cuando se crea una suscripción. Te invitamos a revisar [ask]. Saludos.

Comment: Ahi edite mi consulta. Gracias!